# Relational schema design: "two-to-one" relationship or "backward delete cascade"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema, schema-design

Suppose I have the following schema (just an example) where each customer has
exactly two phone numbers with distinct purposes:

```
create table customer (
    id integer primary key,
    home_phone_id integer not null,
    work_phone_id integer not null,
    foreign key (home_phone_id) references phone (id),
    foreign key (work_phone_id) references phone (id)
);

create table phone (
    id integer primary key,
    number varchar(10) not null
);
```

The foreign keys are placed in the `customer` table in order to distinguish
between the home and work phone numbers. This technically
makes `phone` the "parent" table and `customer` the child, even though a customer
"has" a phone number, not the other way around. (The application would never query for a phone number without its customer.)

When a customer row is deleted, I want its two rows from phone to be
automatically deleted. This is a cascade from a "child" to a "parent", not
from parent to child as is normal. My impression is that no SQL database
supports this behavior. I could use a trigger to accomplish this, but I think
the fact that it's not supported means I'm designing the schema wrong.

I can imagine two alternative designs, neither of which seems very good:

1. Create identical `home_phone` and `work_phone` tables, each
   with a `customer_id`, making `customer` the parent.
2. Make `customer` the parent by moving the foreign key to `phone`, and use an
   extra column in `phone` (like a boolean `is_home`) to distinguish between the two types of phone numbers.

What's the right way to design this?

Comment: option 3: create a third table with customer_id, phone_id, type as a link in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is going to be your best bet.  By moving the `customer_id` to the `phone` table, and adding a new `phone_type` field, you gain two immediate advantages.

1. You now have the `CASCADE DELETE` that you are looking for.
2. This also becomes extendable to adding more phone types in the future.  Perhaps you want to add mobile, secretary, or assistant phone number types.

The actual data in the `phone_type` field can be a standardized list of values, such as: **home**, **work**, **cell**.